# No data send using ajax and old jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a JQuery 3.1.1 by default for a script. For a customer, I must check that my script is compatible with JQuery 1.6.4.

I'm using this to post data :

```
$.ajax({
  url: base_host, //page de l'API
  method: 'POST',
  data: { param1 : "param1"}
});
```

It works perfectly fine using JQuery 3.1.1 and, on my ASP site, I can see that `Request.ContentLength > 0`.
When using JQuery 1.6.4, `Request.ContentLength == 0`

Any idea why this doesn't work in 1.6.4 or how to make it work ?

Comment: **Danger** jQuery 1.6.4 is **unsupported** and has **known security issues**. Tell your client to upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: @Quentin : Good news! I'll tell my client and he'll have to do the job himself ;)

Comment: you should recommend to your customer **not** to use any jQuery versions below `2.x`, better not below `3.x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `method` parameter is not supported before jQuery 1.9.0. You are making a `GET` request and the data is encoded in the query string.

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.